# R Error when saving gt table in R Studio from the viewer

Tags: html, html-table, r-markdown, rstudio, gt

I have created a big gt table and, as I did so many times before, I wanted to save the table as a html document, which I always did via the Viewer/Export/Save as Webpage. It always worked before, but now I am getting this error message:

> [WARNING] Deprecated: --self-contained. use --embed-resources
> --standalone pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\xb9': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream Error:
> pandoc document conversion failed with error 1

I tried to update all packages involved, but the error is still there. There is a blank html file created with 0kb.

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you tagging with [makefile]?

Comment: Oh, I googled the problem and so many times that "makefile" was mentioned. I dont know what it means, but I thought it might be important. Sorry, if not. I can remove it.

Comment: Makefiles are used when you are building a program or package via a compiled language.

Comment: Ok, I will remove it then, thanks.

Comment: All the pages I found say it’s a pandoc encoding issue. Didn’t find any that were using the Rstudio toolchain.

Comment: Same for me. I dont even know what pandoc is. I found now a way round by clicking the icon "Show in new window" at the viewer. The table will then be shown via your internet browser and you can save it from there.

Comment: Maybe you should write up an answer? You can then accept it after some interval, a day or two, if another answer doesn't appear.